# TIMESTAMP to custom duration

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two timestamps and I can get the difference of two using `TIMESTAMP_DIFF`, but I can only get difference in days, hours, minutes etc. What I want is the difference of two in a custom format. For example like "**3D:5H:23M:08S**" or "**03:05:23:08**" or "**3days, 5hours, 23minutes, 8seconds**".

Is this possible to do with BigQuery Standard SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-02-13 13:28:50.532153 UTC' start, TIMESTAMP '2020-03-16 18:51:58.532153 UTC' finish UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-02-13 13:28:50.532153 UTC', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-16 18:51:58.532153 UTC'
)
SELECT -- start, finish, 
  FORMAT('%sD:%s', x, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%HH:%MM:%SS', y)) custom_format1,
  FORMAT('%s:%s', x, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%H:%M:%S', y)) custom_format2,
  FORMAT('%sdays ,%s', x, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Hhours, %Mminutes, %Sseconds', y)) custom_format3
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([CAST(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(finish, start, DAY) AS STRING)]) x,
UNNEST([TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(finish, start, SECOND))]) y
```

with output

```
Row custom_format1  custom_format2  custom_format3   
1   32D:05H:23M:08S 32:05:23:08     32days ,05hours, 23minutes, 08seconds    
2   3D:05H:23M:08S  3:05:23:08      3days ,05hours, 23minutes, 08seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the difference to a timestamp and then use `format_timestamp()` to your heart's content:

```
select TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(timestamp_diff(ts1, t23, millisecond))
```

This gives a timestamp value (probably) in the 1970s, but you are probably only interested in the days, hours, and smaller units.

Comment: How would I get total days out of that? So if difference is 32 days, how do I get 32 instead of 1?

Comment: @Shard . . . What "1"?  You convert the timestamp to whatever representation you want using `format_timestamp()`.

Comment: 1 is number of days.